# How do I test access to a specified database VIEW in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What's a simple SQL query that will just verify I have access to a specified VIEW?

It can be just to pull all the available fields/columns, or just pull the first 10 records of everything; if someone can provide an example with say a VIEW named "LOCATION_DATABASE.ADDRESS_DISPLAY".

```
SELECT TOP 10 FROM LOCATION_DATABASE.ADDRESS_DISPLAY
```

The first 10 records of all fields from the view.

Comment: A `SELECT` requires at least *one* column; you define none.

Comment: Select top 1 * from yourviewname

Comment: You don't even need to return any data, you could use `top 0` and still validate the query with an empty recordset.

Answer (score 0):

Would be:

USE [Database]
GO
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ADDRESS_DISPLAY

It's better to work inside the context of the db.